# Wicket component extended from MultiLineLabel loses multiline when Overriding onComponentTagBody

Tags: java, label, wicket

The output gets rid of \n, just like normal Label .

```
protected void onComponentTagBody(final MarkupStream markupStream, final ComponentTag openTag) {
    String text = getDefaultModelObjectAsString();
    //do other things
    replaceComponentTagBody(markupStream, openTag, text);
}
```

Comment: What is your actual Question?

Comment: Well, what did you expect when you explicitly specified that something else should be in the markup instead?

Comment: I really don't understand why you need to ask 20 times the same question. Perhaps you should formulate the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking questions about failed attempts at circumventing the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wicket sets the text to `Strings.toMultilineMarkup(getDefaultModelObjectAsString())` in `onComponentTagBody`. If you override that method to do something else then it won't work anymore that way.